# Why do airlines ask for passport during boarding and not any other document?

Tags: air-travel, europe

Provided that a person travels within the EU, what is the purpose of verifying the passport? I presume that the company just needs to be sure that I use my own ticket. So why do not they accept a driver's license, for example? Or some other kind of ID?

Comment: Can you give an example, where the airline asked for passport for an EU internal flight during boarding? I've never encountered that.

Comment: @dunni on a flight from Tallinn to Riga. Everyone showed their passports, EU and non-EU citizens

Comment: What do you mean by boarding? Entering the plane or entering the gate?

Comment: Speaking of EU: there are border controls in EU and you need to have a visa to enter UK (as an example). So you have to present your passposrt with a valid UK visa. Speaking of Schengen area: they don't. A lot of people here travelled across Schengen area without showing any ID. And since you're speaking of Tallinn and Riga, the reason maybe just a local desire to control everything and look important. In Moscow's airports you have to present you ID/passport and boarding pass at almost every doorway(!) on your way from check-in counter to the gate.

Comment: Note that just because there is no (regular) border control, doesn't mean that you don't need to bring an ID when travelling to another country. [Here](https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/entry-exit/eu-citizen/index_en.htm) you can see that it's "highly advised" to bring an ID when travelling and that Schengen countries may even make carrying an ID an obligation. It also explicitly states that a driver's license is not a valid ID

Comment: "passport" is easy understandable by all passengers. Often any official ID cards (and driver license) is enough (and I use just my ID card). Note: not all ID cards are the same (some non European countries has just a laminated paper, so not so secure, UK does not have any, driver license is worse [but Europe standardized it]), and we do not want an announcement with a huge list of countries.

Comment: @nsn, entering the plane

Comment: This is just my assumption, but whenever it happened to me, entering the plane, they want to see the ticket and ID. I guess this is just an internal procedure to make sure 1. no one else is flying with your ticket (as most companies you have to pay to exchange the ticket to a new traveller) 2. They want to be sure you actually have a ticket. You could have infiltrated into the airport or be an employee with access to the airfield and join a flight.

Comment: Please note that a driving license might not even be a legal ID document in other countries. In Germany for example it's not.

Comment: When you say EU, I think you mean Schengen area. You will need a passport to travel from say France (in Schengen, in EU) to Ireland (outside Schengen, in EU), but not France to Switzerland (in Schengen, outside EU).

Comment: @thelem but what about travelling from Estonia to Latvia? They both are in Shengen area, arent they? After having read Lassi's answer I now think it is a company's policy to check the passport

Comment: A driver's license is a much less reliable form of identification than a passport or a police-issued ID card (at least here in Sweden, and possibly in other parts of the EU). Our passports and policy-issued ID cards contain RFID chips with digital signatures that make it possible to verify that the passport or ID card is authentic and has a valid issuer. Driver's licenses do not have this feature, and it's a lot harder to verify their authenticity (i.e. they're easier to forge).

Comment: @xuesheng A company can have a stricter policy than the countries they are travelling between, but not looser. You won't find a company that lets you legally travel between a Schengen and a non-Schengen country without a passport.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Airlines ask for a passport, but they don't expect you would necessarily have a passport. They are asking for a [travel document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travel_document) of which passport is an example. Most if not all airlines have conditions of carriage, in which they define which travel documents are valid, but at least in the EU an identity card is accepted. If you want to know more specifically about a certain airline, I would recommend you to read their conditions of carriage.

Specifically to EU, companies are not required to check travel documents, but many still do. This is especially typical to low cost carriers as legacy airlines don't tend to check them as often.

Comment: I'd be amazed if I could board any commercial passenger plane without proving my identity.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider In Europe it is extremely common. I've flown dozens of flights in Europe without having to prove my identity at the gate.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider , aside from TSA, entering a domestic flight in the US does not require ID. You could buy multiple tickets, and use one to go through TSA security, and then board another flight; that is legal and no issue.

Comment: So you mean I could buy a ticket and give it to somebody else? Like, they would not have a passenger manifest? When the plane crashes, they don't know who was on board? They don't know whether all checked luggage's owners are on board?

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider In practice it can be done, but it violates the conditions of carriage. You can also never know beforehand if travel documents are checked at the gate, sometimes carriers do it but often they don't. Regarding luggage an airline knows if the boarding pass associated with the luggage has boarded or not.

Comment: Re "an airline knows if the boarding pass associated with the luggage has boarded or not": Yes, but they don't know whether it's that person, apparently.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider it depends on the country. Speaking from memory, in Spain I have almost always been checked; in Germany, often; in Sweden or Netherlands, rarely..

Comment: I’ve also seen random TSA ID checks at the gate while boarding a plane in the US (several TSA officers would show up at a gate and check that IDs matched boarding passes as people boarded) but it’s _rare_ – it’s happened to me maybe twice on the 700+ flights I’ve taken since the TSA’s been around, and I haven’t had it happen in a few years.

Answer (score 1):

I fell in the same situation a year ago. I showed my EU driver's license at check in desk but was refused checking in because the clerk stated that `driver's license does not show nationality`. Then I gave her my national ID card and everything was ok.

First, the question "please show me your **passport**" is likely a mantra as stated by @Lassi. Just like when you are checked *tickets* in a bus but officers ask you to show `passes, please` (in the sense of the monthly/seasonal pass used by frequent commuters).

Anyone can get a driver's license in any EU country regardless of his/her nationality. So the driver's license can never be accepted because does not prove EU citizenship. Only the ability to drive a motor vehicle of corresponding EU category.

Now to Schengen agreement: while it is commonly called to be "no borders" (and no checks) between countries, mind that freedom of circulation in Schengen space is a right granted only to Schengen citizens. So you basically have to prove the airline that you are a Schengen citizen to travel the Schengen area.

That is what was told me.

Comment: Also, there are exceptions to the "no checks between countries" upon arrival as well. For example, when travelling from Palermo to Lyon last year, everyone's passport was checked upon arrival. And Sweden has had passport controls when arriving by train from Denmark for the last couple of years.

Comment: "driver's license does not show nationality": why is nationality relevant for an internal flight?  Are there actual laws that require airlines to check whether their passengers are authorized to cross internal Schengen borders?  There's certainly nothing on the topic in the Schengen codes, nor even any provisions relating to what is necessary for a third-country national to cross an internal border.

Comment: "freedom of circulation in Schengen space is a right granted only to Schengen citizens": and other EU citizens.  But actually, the Schengen Borders Code and the Lisbon treaty on which it is based refer to "free movement of persons," not of citizens.  The point is to reduce friction at internal borders.  Requiring a check of immigration status is friction that is at odds with the stated aim.  The free movement of noncitizens across internal borders is implied by the free movement of citizens, because if noncitizens' movement is restricted, citizens would have to be subjected to controls.

Answer (score -2):

Because the only country in the world where a drivers license is an identification document is the USA. 
In the rest of the civilized world a passport or a national ID card are the only valid identifcation documents.

Comment: In fact, the USA isn't the only such country.  Canada, for one, doesn't have national ID cards either.

Comment: Also in Europe, where there are ID cards in most countries, driving licenses are often used for day to day identification. Not always officially allowed but still often used.

Comment: Nonsense. In France for example, you can prove your identity any way you like – [it's the law](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichTexte.do?cidTexte=JORFTEXT000025582411&dateTexte=&categorieLien=id). Passports and ID cards are only *examples* of how to prove it. Driver's license, social security card, a bus pass with a photo, etc are all valid ways of proving your identity. If stopped in the street and asked to prove your identity, you can even ask someone vouch for you. Please don't post such blatant disinformation. If you don't know, just don't say anything.